# How do required input if second input is not empty?

Tags: javascript

Please help: I have two input fields and I need do required Name if second Phone is not empty and conversely.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control" asp-for="Name" value="@Model.Name" />

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter phone" class="form-control" asp-for="Phone" value="@Model.Phone" />
```

I have to do it at the front.

Comment: Why not just add the `required` attribute to both? It seems they are both actually required. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you required *both* input fields to be filled out if at least one of them has some content. You can achieve this by dynamically checking all input fields and setting the `required` attribute accordingly:

```js
const inps=[...document.frm1.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")];
document.frm1.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 const someAreFilled=inps.some(el=>el.value>"");
 inps.forEach(el=>el.required=someAreFilled);
})
```

```html
<form name="frm1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control" asp-for="Name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter phone" class="form-control" asp-for="Phone"/>
<button>go</button>
</form>
```

This snippet will work with as many text input fields as there are in your form. Currently all `input[type=text]` elements will be included in the checks. You can make the selector more specific by e. g. looking for a particular class.